# C++ socket multithreading: how to reduce vector size

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, c++11, vector

So I am learning std::thread in C++ 11 and I want to use it with std::vector on my socket programming.

I've search for std::thread tutorial and it seems to me that many people are using std::thread with containers, such as std::vector.

My problem is:

1. What is benefit of using std::thread with std::vector?
2. I am implementing my C++ socket server with std::thread and std::vector (code below), and I found out a problem:

   If a client connects to my server, my server will create a thread and store it in std::vector, which will increase size of std::vector. If that client disconnects and reconnects to my server again, it will create a thread again for that connection and increase std::vector size. However, elements remain even if thread is done. So, if a client repeatedly connects/disconnects to my server, the size of std::vector will increase until the machine runs out of memory. Is there a way to detect a thread is complete(or client disconnects) and delete the element of std::vector?

Below is my implementation: assume all TCP set up are done and the socket listening part looks like this:

```
// things to do after connection established
void do_something(int sockfd)
{
    // do something
}

int main()
{
    /* ------------
        TCP socket setup here ...
       ------------*/

    std::vector <std::thread> MyThreads;

    // server waiting for connections
    while(1)
    {
        std::cout << "Listening..." << std::endl;
        new_sockfd = accept(socked, (struct sockaddr *)&ClientAddress, &len);
        MyThreads.push_back(std::move(std::thread(do_something, new_sockfd)));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You will need to write the necessary code for a thread to notify the main execution thread that the running thread is done, after which the thread immediately terminates. The parent thread, upon being notified, joins the exiting thread, then removes the corresponding `std::thread` from the vector. Multithreading is hard. There is no magic button you can simply push, and have everything done for you. You will need to write all the code to implement all of this functionality, by yourself. The only way to do it is for you to keep reading your C++ book, and learning.

Comment: What do you need the vector *for*?

Comment: It'd be wise to check [ASIO](https://think-async.com/).

Comment: I'll expand on my question. You don't *need* a collection of accepted sockets. Each thread has its own socket and can manage it independently. The only time you need a collection of sockets, or better still clients, is when you want to broadcast to all of them, which is rare.

Comment: @EJP oh I see, so the need of vector is to broadcasting to clients. I wasn't sure I need a vector, just learning thread on internet and see lots of tutorial (like cppreference) use it with vector.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks for the tips, I will keep reading. Btw, so if I can detect a thread is done, I will have to loop through all vector and find the element that is done right?

Comment: @EJP: "***The only time** you need a collection of sockets ... is when you want to broadcast to all of them*" - that is not the only time. Keeping track of the clients can be useful for a number of things. Disconnecting active clients when shutting down the server. Without a container, you would have to keep a counter of accepted clients, make the threads decrement that counter when done, and watch it until it reaches 0. With a container, you can just loop through the threads calling `join()` on them. Another reason would be if you need to detect duplicate client logins. Just to name a couple.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: yes, if you have a container of socket threads, you would have to loop through the container looking for each thread that is done running. For instance, define a struct that contains the `std::thread` and a `bool`. Add a struct instance to the `vector`, set its `bool` to false, and start its thread. When the thread is done, have it set its own struct's `bool` to true before exiting. Then your main thread can periodically loop through the `vector`, and for any element whose `bool` is true, `join` the thread and then remove the element from the `vector`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the reply. Now I know why using vector with thread, seems pretty useful!